# Do you need to allocate and init properties in a class?

Tags: objective-c

So when we want to use a class we do something like

```
MyClass *exampleClass = [[MyClass alloc] init ];
```

My question is how can we use the Classe's properties ? If a class does not alloc and init the properties?

When we alloc/init the class does it automatically alloc/init every property ?

My confusion happens because lets say I'm in class A. 
Say I have a property that is a `NSMutableArray (strong) *myArray;`

I want to insert an object to it. First I have to check if it is allocated and initialized if it is not i would have to do it.

If i try to do something like

```
[_myArray insertObject.....] 
it won't do anything because its nill. 
I have to do something like, which i understand. 
if(!_myArray)
_myArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This is very confusing because i have a class with properties and none of them are initialized by me. 
But when i use and instance of that class they all work without init/alloc of the properties.

Comment: If you assign nothing to a property it takes its default value.  The default value for a pointer property is `nil`.

Comment: (And note that you can do method calls on a `nil` pointer, assign array values to a `nil` array, et al, and no errors will occur.  In fact nothing at all will occur.)

Comment: If you know you always want to have `myArray` be an NSMutableArray then add the code to your `init` method to create the array and assign it to `myArray`.  There is no need to "guard" this with a `if` statement, since `init` is only executed once, when the object is created.

Answer (score 0):

Objects must be initialised using [[TheClass alloc ]init] or [TheClass new] @"", @[ ] etc.
Primitive properties (floats, ints, BOOLs etc) don't need to initialised they just need to be set to some value.
If you are reading an object property as valid that has not been initialised somewhere you have overlooked something.

Comment: Hey bro I think you solved my problem. I think my NSString property is set by @"" somewhere. Or by a variable that is set that way....

Comment: This does make sense because my MutableArray is nil but not my string. That is because i didnt know you can use @"" to init/alloc !!! thanks again. I have to go to work, ill probably be late but...

Comment: Sweet, my first successful answer. @"" is the same as [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@""]; Essentially its a shorthand to alloc, init an object. Known as literals incase you didn't know.

Comment: One needs to distinguish between initializing an *object* and initializing a *property* (which is either a primitive or an object *pointer*).

Comment: @Hot Licks Right so, when an object is initialised, if the properties are set to defaults nil/NO/NULL then  memory must be allocated for each property. So what you are saying is that the properties of an object have space in memory that is separate to any memory allocated to the objects that are pointed to by the properties. Is that correct?

Comment: @KristianFox - Pointers to objects are allocated separate from the objects they point to, yes.

Comment: Ha, seems totally obvious when you put it like that.

Answer (score 0):

After a call to [SomeClass alloc], the result is an object with all instance variables set to 0, nil, NO, NULL etc. If you want your instance variables to contain anything else then you have to implement that in your init method. If these 0, nil, NO, NULL values are Ok then you don't need any further initialisation.

Answer (score -1):

Object properties will be nil unless they are initialized.  This is the main purpose of the init method.  Another common pattern is to create lazy initialization in your getters, so:

Either...

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _myArray = [NSArray array];  // use _notation here and in setter/getters but not elsewhere
    }
    return self;
}
```

or, lazy init...

```
- (NSArray *)myArray {
    if (!_myArray) {
        _myArray = [NSArray array];
    }
    return _myArray;  // again, elsewhere, use self.myArray, not _myArray
}
```

Comment: Why do the properties in a class i created work if i didn't implement these initializers ?

Comment: Non-scalar properties you define on your object will absolutely start out nil.  If you see them not nil after creation, then somewhere your code is  initializing them (or your phone is inhabited by magic elves).

Comment: Sorry i think you didnt understand me.

Comment: Im talking about why don't we need to initialize the instance variable of an object. I say this because i created a class and i didn't initialize anything in the class definition. I do initialize the object itself. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: There is no requirement that properties be "initialized".  They will take the default value if you never assign anything to them.

Comment: is nill a default value ? I'm having trouble because i created a new project to test things out and the properties are all nil so i can't assign anything to them. But in one of my projects i have a NSString propery and i never initialize it and it somehow works.

Comment: @HotLicks - the answer is in context of the OP which thinks that properties are given value somehow implicitly.  "must be initialized" meant "must be initialized through code you write if you want them to have non-nil value".  I edited.